# How to Authenticate in Office 365 with Oauth using poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin in Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, oauth-2.0, office365, jenkins-plugins

I'm stuck configuring poll-mailbox-trigger plugin in Jenkins since basic authentication became deprecated.
I managed to get App ID, Secret, and tenant id but even when i set the authentication mechanism to Xauth2, i still get `Error : javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.`

Here's my Advanced Email properties:

```
mail.debug.auth=true
mail.imaps.port=993
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.imaps.ssl.enable=true
mail.imaps.starttls.enable=true
 
subjectContains=Test
mail.imap.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2
```

Please if you managed to login, please help me to solve this blocking problem

Adding mail.imap.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2 and putting secret as password.